# Is there any example like jQuery-chosen in pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, jquery-chosen

Actually I am trying to make a combobox (dropdown+input text field) in JavaScript. There is an awesome example of combobox in jQuery [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Is there any kind of examples written in pure Javascript?

Comment: IS there any specific reason for using only JS?

Comment: I'm with user1671639. jQuery is written in pure JS, you know, to handle complex browser support of things such as event handlers, that varies a great deal between browsers. You'll be dealing with event handling. Oh, and sizes and positioning. These things will be essential to your component, so you will write them. And you'll end up with a handmade mini jQuery, probably less optimized and less tested.

Comment: there are none in pure js, may be u can write and give us the github link :)

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery because of page performance purposes

Comment: Actually I've written one, but it's not upto that level,,,,please contribute and fork ,,https://github.com/RUPOJS/jsCombo

Comment: Are you experiencing performance issues with jQuery? My experience is that if you want it, as you say, *up to that level*, you'll have to write a lot of the code that jQuery has already done a brilliant job at providing. Sure, if you just want a shorthand for `getElementById` then the jQuery library is a lot of overhead, but since you're actually going to have to solve a lot of the problems that jQuery was invented to solve, chances are you're going to write something that'll perform worse, even if it doesn't use any libraries.

Comment: yeah,,you are right but the performance and size of the files matters ,,,and please see once DHTMLX combo,,,it performs better than the chosen :)

Comment: @ropoJS Great dude.  But you should have mentioned that first that you're writing a plugin with pure JS :)

Comment: +1, why would I use jQuery for very very small projects.

Answer (score 0):

javascript code :

```
function select()
{
var selectedvalue=list.options[list.selectedIndex].text;
alert(selectedvalue);
}
```

Html :

```
<select id="list" onchange="select()">
  <option></option>
  <option>option 1</option>
  <option>option 2</option>  
  <option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

This is a pure javascript code for dropdown list,you can show the selected value in input text field using DOM.